# Modify Legend using ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm currently using the ggplot package to plot a histogram of normal variates with a N(0, 1) density overlay. I'm very new to this package and the code I'm using is

```
x = rnorm(1000)
qplot(x, geom = 'blank') +     
  geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., colour = 'Histogram'), legend = FALSE, 
  binwidth = 0.5, fill = "blue") +                        
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(colour = 'Density'))+
  scale_x_continuous('x', limits = c(-4, 4))+
  opts(title = "Histogram with Overlay")+
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Legend', values = c('darkblue', 'red')) +
  scale_y_continuous('Frequency')+
  opts(legend.key=theme_rect(fill="white",colour="white"))+
  opts(legend.background = theme_rect())
```

This code produces the following diagram. How do I change the legend so that the line representing the histogram is replaced with a filled blue box (that represents the bars of the histogram)? Thank You!

[image: Histogram With Overlay]

Comment: also check out `geom_density()`. Easier than `stat_function(...)` IMHO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this...

```
dat = data.frame(x=rnorm(1000))  
ggplot(dat,aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill="Histogram"),binwidth=0.5) + 
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, aes(colour= "Density")) +
    scale_x_continuous('x', limits = c(-4, 4)) + 
    opts(title = "Histogram with Overlay") +
    scale_fill_manual(name="",value="blue") + 
    scale_colour_manual(name="",value="red") + 
    scale_y_continuous('Frequency')+
    opts(legend.key=theme_rect(fill="white",colour="white"))+
    opts(legend.background = theme_blank())
```

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`. So for example, the last two lines above would be:

```
theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white",colour = "white")) + 
theme(legend.background = element_blank())
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, but now the legend seems to be split into two legends, and also there are no lines separating the bars of the histogram.

Comment: Adding `colour='black'` to `geom_histogram` outside of `aes` will bring back the lines on the bars but will add a diagonal line in the legend. There are two legends because that's the way you get what you described in ggplot2, end of story. If you want extremely fine control over legends, stick to base plotting functions. ggplot2 is resisting you here because you're trying to create an arguably "bad" legend, or at least an unnecessary one according to the philosophy behind ggplot2.

Comment: The key=list() argument to xyplot would also allow adjustment of line width in the legend.

Comment: There is a typo: `theme(legend.background = elemenet_blank())`, should be `element_blank`

Comment: I tried, but the system does not allow such a minor edit, at least 6 chars, it said. :)